# Show error message if form empty in google amp

Tags: html, amp-html

Is there any way to show an error message if a form is empty in AMP(i.e none of the fields have any value?). I tried the following, but it does not seem to work(Please not the `div.error` node).

```
<form method="POST" id="my-form" class="p2" action-xhr="/components/amp-form/submit-form" target="_top" custom-validation-reporting="show-first-on-submit">
  <p>My Form</p>
  <div class="error" visible-when-invalid="valueMissing" validation-for="my-form">
    Form is empty could not submit.
  </div>
  <div>
    <input required id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
    <input required id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: Follow the guide here: [Success/error response rendering](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form#success/error-response-rendering) or [Custom validations](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form#custom-validations) that shows how to properly perform validations and showing response when a form is submitted. Also try checking their [samples](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/) for `amp-form`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with validation state invalid like `on="invalid:error.show"`

invalid : The form's validation state to "invalid" (in accordance with its [reporting strategy](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form#reporting-strategies)).

```
<form method="POST" id="my-form" class="p2" action-xhr="/components/amp-form/submit-form" target="_top" on="invalid:error.show" custom-validation-reporting="show-first-on-submit">
  <p>My Form</p>
  <div class="error" id="error" hidden>
    Form is empty could not submit.
  </div>
  <div>
    <input required id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
    <input required id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" name="password">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```